# В чем разница между функциями первого порядка и callback функциями?

Tags: javascript, callback

Насколько я понимаю, это одно и тоже. Но мне не понятно, почему *callback* функция называется так. Кому она и что возвращает?

Есть ли разница между функциями первого порядка и *callback* функциями?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Дам отрывок [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/428570/)

> В JavaScript с функциями можно делать то же самое, что можно делать с
> сущностями других типов, таких, как Object, String, Number. Функции
> можно передавать как параметры другим функциям. Такие функции,
> переданные другим, обычно выступают в роли функций обратного вызова
> (коллбэков). Функции можно назначать переменным, хранить их в
> массивах, и так далее. Именно поэтому функции в JS — это объекты
> первого класса.

Как видно в JS все функции являются объектами первого класса, а вот коллбэки это только переданные в параметре других функций, для вызова ее из функции. Результат любая функция не обязана что либо возращать, коллбэк не исключение. И не путайте определения *объекты **первого** класса* (first-class objects) и *функции **высшего** порядка* (Higher-Order Function). (У вас получился Франкенштейн.)

> Функции высшего порядка — это функции, которые работают с другими
> функциями, либо принимая их в виде параметров, либо возвращая их.
> Проще говоря, функцией высшего порядка называется такая функция,
> которая принимает функцию как аргумент или возвращает функцию в виде
> выходного значения.
>
> Например, встроенные функции JavaScript Array.prototype.map,
> Array.prototype.filter и Array.prototype.reduce являются функциями
> высшего порядка.

Comment: Если вы пишете кому-то комментарий с @имя под  сообщением, то если это сообщение удалить, то и никакого уведемления не будет. Просто пишите комментарий под любым другим сообщением.

Comment: @0xdb ясно спасибо буду иметь ввиду